# IT Security SE Logo Wallpaper

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Just wanted to post here, to officially request something that was mentioned in chat:  An IT Security StackExchange wallpaper.

I think the main site's "banner logo" (including:  lion, shield, starburst, wings, "Tron lines", banner) would look great against its current backdrop color, as a full-sized desktop wallpaper.  Someone skilled with Photoshop or other like programs could probably hack together a reasonable likeness, but it would be much preferable to have an "official" wallpaper from the design-master himself.

So, @Jin, could we please?

I'm putting the top 10 screen resolutions, as reported by StatCounter GlobalStats, as a suggestion here.  (Thanks, @ThomasPornin!)  My personal request is for 1280x1024.  Please add others via edit or comment to this post, as necessary.

- 1024 x 768
- 1280 x 800

  - Iszi
- 1366 x 768
- 1280 x 1024

  - Iszi
- 1440 x 900
- 1680 x 1050

  - Rory Alsop
- 1920 x 1080

  - Iszi
- 1600 x 900
- 1152 x 864
- 1360 x 768
- 1920 x 1200

  - M'vy

Comment: You can list all the popular resolutions?

Comment: Also a great way to promote the site

Comment: @Jin - had to laugh - I only just got the sarcasm/snark :-)

Comment: Who did the original design?

Comment: @D3C4FF Jin did the site design, and the original wallpapers posted [here](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/652/953).

Comment: How come we don't have a logo wallpaper with the Bears yet !! :P

Answer (score 12):

I like Jeff Ferland's suggestion to make a few wallpapers based on common aspect ratios. So here they are:

[image: IT Security Wallpaper]

[2560x2048](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdwss.png)
Ratio: 5:4
Common Resolutions: 1280x1024

[2560x1920](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K25CR.png)
Ratio: 4:3
Common Resolutions: 1024x768, 1152x864

[2560x1600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWFzq.png)
Ratio: 8:5
Common Resolutions: 1280x800, 1440x900, 1680x1050, 1920x1200

[2560x1440](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfyKN.png)
Ratio: 16:9
Common Resolutions: 1920x1080, 1600x900

I also made a bigger and more detailed logo(600x600px), against a solid color(#112a3d). That way you can map it to whatever sized wallpaper you like.

[image: IT Security Logo, detailed]

and with subtle scanline background:

[image: IT Security Logo, detailed with scanline]

if you want to reproduce the scaline pattern, the lighter line is #112a3d and the darker line is #0e2232. or you can use image below as a tile pattern.

[image: scan line pattern]

Just for fun, a stoney version (background color #2f2f2f)

[image: IT Security Logo, stone]

Enjoy!

Comment: If anyone manages to build custom-sized versions of any of the above, could they upload them here?

Answer (score 10):

@TidalWave made this riff from @Jin's original design, to include one of our dearly beloved mods. The full image size is 2560 x 2048.

[image]

Comment: Ohhh! You like me, you really *like* me!

Answer (score 7):

I've been asked to prepare another customized wallpaper, this time with our beloved Sec.SE moderator [@RoryAlsop](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/485/rory-alsop). It's again based on @Jin's original design, with a cut-out from Rory's own photo:

[image: sec.se rocks]

And another, slightly less modified version:

[image: rockin' in the mod world]

Of course, for our beloved [@Jeff Ferland](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/836/jeff-ferland), slightly different approach was in order:

[image]

Resolution is for all 2560 x 2048. Hope you like them ;)

Answer (score 4):

@Jin - I still think this is a good idea. Still trying to figure out whether the best looking one would have just the logo, logo and large title or logo and minimal title at the bottom, but in any case... a good idea if you can create this.

Alternatively - If you have the core image files, you can ping em through and I can build wallpaper images in Photoshop.

Comment: Rory I still plan on doing this for sure. I just need to get some other design tasks out of the way first.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion: Instead of building images for each size, build images for the largest expected size for common aspect ratios. Based upon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution#Computer_Monitors, I suggest every image is 2560 pixels wide and fits the aspect ratios 16:10, 16:9, 4:3, and 5:4.

```
2560    16  10  1600
        16  9   1440
        4   3   1920
        5   4   2048
```

People or operating systems can scale down from there.

Comment: Although scaling doesn't work so well on the one with the lines :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop Oops!

Comment: isn't the end of the world, as @Jin has provided the scanline background so we can sort them out. I'm planning on doing ones for my widescreen monitors at home